# How to integrate with identity provider to make a SSO with it using CakePhp 2.6?

Tags: php, cakephp, single-sign-on, integration, saml

I have CakePhp project and I need to integrate with an external identity provider system to make a Single sign-on (SSO) with it, because I'm new to SAML and I need a help to understand the process of doing this.